# Python: Find values with same date and calculate difference

Tags: python, pandas

I am struggling with this code, i am sure there must be a straight forward solution for it.

I have got a dataframe with dates and values. Basically, i want to see the difference the values for the same date. I know how to sum them up but how can i see the delta between them? So How can i create the column "Difference"? Like this:

```
DateTime            Values          Difference
06/12/2016 00:00    58              25
06/12/2016 00:15    75              63
06/12/2016 00:30    66              -79
06/12/2016 00:45    23              11
06/12/2016 01:00    17              -537
06/12/2016 00:00    33  
06/12/2016 00:15    12  
06/12/2016 00:30    145 
06/12/2016 00:45    12  
06/12/2016 01:00    55


filename = path + "Forecast.csv"
test = pd.read_csv(filename)
df2 = test.groupby('DateTime')['Values'].sum()
```

Is there a way to calculate the difference not the sum?

Thanks for your support!

Regards,

O Vizzle

Comment: `test.groupby('DateTime')['Values'].diff()` should work

Comment: tried it, won't work. Just empty cells...

Comment: Actually I think you want `test['Difference'] = test.groupby(test['DateTime'].dt.date)['Values'].transform('diff')`

Comment: Thanks! that worked as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to sort first

```
df.set_index('DateTime').sort_index().groupby(level=0).diff(-1).dropna()
```

[image]

---

To match exactly what you had

```
df.join(
    df.sort_values('DateTime').groupby('DateTime') \
      .diff(-1).dropna().rename(columns={'Values': 'Difference'})
).fillna('')
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what i was looking for! Thanks for that.

The only thing is, that i have more columns than 2 in the original table.. So then it won't work.. how can i tell python to add the difference column at the end of the last filled column?

Comment: see below..

Thanks

Comment: `df.join(df.sort_values('DateTime').groupby('DateTime').Value3.diff(-1).dropna().to_frame('Difference')).fillna('')`

Comment: Thanks for that!

Somehow the part Value3 in the code seems to be not working. I already tried to insert ['Value3'] but still won't work.

What could be the problem?


And sorry for posting an answer earlier... I wasn't able to insert a picture so i posted my question as an answer... sorry